Fail to build FMU during code generation in Matlab using CATIA-Systems / FMIKit-Simulink
I am trying to create a model exchange FMU using your the tool 3.1 in Matlab 2021a. I am generating rtwsfcnfmi.tlc target. Always I get this:
The call to rtwsfcnfmi_make_rtw_hook, during the after_make hook generated the following error:
Failed to build FMU.
here is the whole report given by matlab:
`Generating code and artifacts to 'Model specific' folder structure
Generating code into build folder: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi
Invoking Target Language Compiler on simple.rtw
Using System Target File: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\rtwsfcnfmi\rtwsfcnfmi.tlc
Loading TLC function libraries
Generating TLC interface API for custom data
Initial pass through model to cache user defined code
Caching model source code
Writing header file simple_sf_types.h
Writing header file simple_sf.h
Writing header file rtwtypes.h
Writing header file multiword_types.h
Writing source file simple_sf.c
Writing header file simple_sf_private.h
Writing header file simple_sid.h
Writing header file simple_mid.h
Writing source file simple_sf_data.c
Writing header file rtGetNaN.h
Writing source file rtGetNaN.c
Writing header file rt_nonfinite.h
Writing source file rt_nonfinite.c
Writing header file rt_defines.h
Writing header file rtGetInf.h
Writing source file rtGetInf.c

TLC code generation complete.
Writing modelDescription.xml
Generating project
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27045.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27045.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
FIPXT_SHARED_MODULE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/xxx/Documents/MATLAB/xxx/test fmi/FMIKit-Simulink-3.1/cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64/bin/simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi

Building FMU
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Checking Build System
Building Custom Rule C:/Users/xxx/Documents/MATLAB/xxx/test fmi/FMIKit-Simulink-3.1/rtwsfcnfmi/CMakeLists.txt
ode1.c
ode1.vcxproj -> C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi\Release\ode1.lib
Building Custom Rule C:/Users/xxx/Documents/MATLAB/xxx/test fmi/FMIKit-Simulink-3.1/rtwsfcnfmi/CMakeLists.txt
fmi2Functions.c
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\rtwsfcnfmi\fmi2Functions.c(130): warning C4028: Formal parameter 2 differs from declaration. [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi\simple.vcxproj]
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\rtwsfcnfmi\fmi2Functions.c(273): warning C4028: Formal parameter 2 differs from declaration. [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi\simple.vcxproj]
sfunction.c
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\rtwsfcnfmi\sfunction.c(18): warning C4005: R2020b: macro redefinition [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi\simple.vcxproj]
c:\program files\polyspace\r2021a\extern\include\matrix.h(53): note: see previous definition R2020b
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\rtwsfcnfmi\sfunction.c(19): warning C4005: R2017b: macro redefinition [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi\simple.vcxproj]
c:\program files\polyspace\r2021a\extern\include\matrix.h(35): note: see previous definition R2017b
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\rtwsfcnfmi\sfunction.c(306): error C2039: mdlInfoSLSize: Is not a member of _ssBlkInfo2. [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi\simple.vcxproj]
c:\program files\polyspace\r2021a\simulink\include\simstruc_def.h(709): note: see declaration: _ssBlkInfo2
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\rtwsfcnfmi\sfunction.c(306): error C2027: Use of undefined type _ssMdlInfoSLSize [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi\simple.vcxproj]
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\rtwsfcnfmi\sfunction.c(306): note: see declaration: _ssMdlInfoSLSize
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\rtwsfcnfmi\sfunction.c(308): error C2039: mdlInfoSLSize: Is not a member of _ssBlkInfo2. [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\MATLAB\xxx\test fmi\FMIKit-Simulink-3.1\cmake-3.22.2-windows-x86_64\bin\simple_sfcn_rtw_fmi\simple.vcxproj]
c:\program files\polyspace\r2021a\simulink\include\simstruc_def.h(709): note: see declaration: _ssBlkInfo2
rt_matrx_wrapper.c
model_interface.c
rtGetInf.c
rtGetNaN.c
sfcn_fmi.c
simple_sf_data.c`

For test purposes I made really simple model from scratch. I tried .slx, .mdl formats, newer or older versions, nothing works.
